# comparing text similarity using Sequence Matcher: why do results differ for lowercase and uppercase strings?

Tags: python, text, nlp, similarity

I have a set of text (alphanumeric) in a pandas dataframe and I would like to calculate the similarity scores for pairs of text (e.g. text 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4...).

I am using Sequence Matcher for the calculations and was able to get a score.  I thought it would also be worth comparing text after they have been converted into lowercase. I created 2 score columns to compare the results:
score 1 = similarity score from pairs of non-lowercase text (original case of text retained)
score 2 = similarity score from pairs of lowercase text.

I expected for the similarity scores for the lowercase text pairs (score 2) to be higher, since there would be more characters matching (e.g. "This SamPle pHrase" would match with "this sample phrase" therefore higher similarity). However, I found in some instances that score 1 is way higher than score 2. Would any of you have ideas on why this might be the case?

I have tried to search in python documentation and googled for possible reasons, but could not find any. What am I missing? I'd like to understand this more, I'd appreciate any ideas/suggestions! Cheers

Btw I used str.lower to convert the text in the dataframe into lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly (using [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/sequencematcher-in-python-6b1e6f3915fc) as a source), the Sequence Matcher matches common sequences, and returns a score based on the **number of shared sequences**.

This is not what you want. If you use all lower-case, there will be longer common sequences, but fewer of them.

It's the wrong tool. Sequence Matcher might work fine for the similarity of gene sequences, coin tosses, or other related things, but is not really suitable for the similarity between texts.

In order to choose the right metric, you first have to be clear about *why* you are doing this. What do you mean by "similarity between pairs of texts"? This is a non-trivial question, and the answer depends very much on the purpose of your analysis.

Typical measures could be the frequency distributions of words, with or without stemming, either per sentence or per paragraph. Or you could use word-level Levenshtein distance. Comparing texts pairwise word-for-word makes very little sense.